# Constructing a homeomorphism with some properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Let $p,q\in \mathbb{R}$ with $p\neq q$. Find a homeomorphism $h\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(p)=q$ and $$h\big\vert_{\mathbb{R}\setminus M}=\operatorname{id}$$ where $M$ is an arbitrary bounded set.

My idea:

Clearly this function looks like this
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus M\\ f(x) & x\in M\end{cases}$$

So let $M=[t_1,t_2]$ then clearly we must have $t_1\leq q\leq t_2$ and since we need continuity, we need $f'(t_1)=f'(t_2)=1$.

My attempt was to use $f(x)=\sin(x)$ because $$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\sin(0)=\cos(0)=1$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}\sin(2\pi)=\cos(2\pi)=1$$

So my function becomes
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus M\\ q+\sin(k\cdot x) &  x\in M=[q,q+\pi/2]\end{cases} $$

Because $p$ must be hit by sinus and sinus is only homeomorphic $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, we must find a factor $k$ such that we can stretch sinus on $M=[q,q+\pi/2]$ such that $$q+\sin(k\cdot x)=p\implies k=\frac{\arcsin{p-q}}{x}$$

Now I need a second subfunction $g(x)$ to connect with the identity line again.

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus (M\cup N)\\ q+\sin(\arcsin{p-q}) &  x\in M=[q,q+2\pi]
\\ g(x) &  x\in N=[q+2\pi,t_3]\end{cases} $$

But here I get stuck. How do I now find a function $g(x)$ to connect with the identity line $f(x)=x$ again? And is it correct so far?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be well posed. What if $p\in \mathbb R \setminus M?$

Comment: @zhw. We have that $p\neq q$ so $p$ can not be in $\mathbb{R}\setminus M$ because otherwise $h(p)=p=q$

Comment: But you said $M$ was an arbitrary bounded set.

Comment: @zhw. Yes and clearly $p\in M$ since otherwise $h(p)=p=q$. The set is arbitrary but we have the condition that $h(x)$ must be the identity function on $\mathbb{R}\setminus M$ and that $h(p)=q$, hence this implies $p\in M$, otherwise this would only work if $p=q$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aiming for more smoothness than required, thereby making your function unnecessarily complicated.

Pick $t_1<\min\{p,q\}$ and $t_2>\max\{p,q\}$. Then you can use
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\le t_1\\
t_1+\frac{q-t_1}{p-t_1}(x-t_1)&t_1\le x\le p\\
t_2+\frac{q-t_2}{p-t_2}(x-t_2)&p\le x\le t_2\\
x&x\ge t_2\end{cases} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!